# razor misreads closing brace inside script while in section

Tags: syntax, razor, curly-braces

In this piece of code Razor thinks that closing brace of function definition is a closing brace of section:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        function a() {
            var x = @(Model.Id);
        }
    </script>
}
```

This happens only when script's content in section contains Razor "injections" (@(Model.Id in this case). How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: I had the same issue Today, fortunately I had the luxury to move the script from head section to body

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this line of code and it works fine. But maybe it's because I have the JScript editor extensions plugin for Visual studio installed..

Comment: I have JScript Editor extensions installed as well. And yet I see the following: https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=e216020aeeebc879&resid=E216020AEEEBC879!651&parid=E216020AEEEBC879!178

Comment: Put the curly bracket after scripts on the next line as you have in the example here.

Comment: Won't help. And now I've confirmed that I'm not the only one as my colleague has the same issue. The "solution" for now is to put scripts in a partial view and render partial in a section - sad..